# Highscore PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to make a *high score* table for my website
I'm using PHP and I got a PDO setup

I got 2 tables

**logs**

```
id       -- the id of incoming log
user_id  -- User ID
```

**users**

```
ID       -- User ID
username -- Username
password -- Pass
email    -- email
```

I want to count how many logs come in per `user_id`, and show which `user_id/username` got the most logs
And i must show the username so it must be linked by ID's

I've used this to get the total user count:

```
// functions.php: 
class stats {
    function totalUsers($db) { 
        $SQL = $db -> query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
        return $SQL->fetchColumn(0); 
    } 
} 

// index.php
require_once 'includes/functions.php;
echo $stats -> totalUsers($db);
```

Comment: In terms of code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used this to get the total user count:

functions.php:
`class stats
{
 function totalUsers($db)
 {
  $SQL = $db -> query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`");
  return $SQL->fetchColumn(0);
 }


}
?>`

index.php

`require_once 'includes/functions.php;
 <?php echo $stats -> totalUsers($db); ?>`

Havent really figured a working way to get the highscores, thats pretty much the reason why im posting here

Comment: `require_once 'includes/functions.php;` if that's your real code, there's a quote missing for it. Do `require_once 'includes/functions.php';`

Comment: Got messed up while editing post. it is with the quote
Thanks for the heads up though

Answer (score 0):

Use the group by clause in mysql

```
 $SQL = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs GROUP BY user_id");
```

You can get the user information if you join the tables

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT users.id, users.email, COUNT(logs.*) 
               FROM logs 
             LEFT JOIN logs.user_id = users.ID
             GROUP BY logs.user_id"

 $sqlResults = $db->query($sqlQuery );
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on this, on the $sqlResults variable
`
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sqlResults' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\n\p\m=panel\index.php on line 24
`

I've added this straight into the index.php where the highscore should be.

Comment: Yeah. That's probably because you copied my code verbatim without stopping to figure if it is correct. Did you notice I have a semicolon missing on the first statement? My answer was meant to help you to understand HOW to solve this issue, not to write source code for you.